# What does rabbitmq-server.service do?

Tags: boot, 18.04, rabbitmq

*Hello, I've started using Ubuntu 18.04 a year ago and I'm not an expert.*

I was trying to remove service that I don't need on boot.
As you can see I have [rabbitmq-server.service](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rabbitmq-server.1.html) which takes almost 30s. So i was thinking i could disable/remove it, because I don't think I'm using it.

But I don't really know what it does and in which way it could affect my experience if I remove it. So that's my question.

```
❯ systemd-analyze blame
         27.681s rabbitmq-server.service
         20.728s solr.service
         15.742s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          7.687s docker.service
          6.098s snapd.service
          6.090s neo4j.service
          3.455s tor@default.service
          1.628s apache2.service
          1.470s dev-zram0.device
          1.458s dev-zram1.device
          1.444s dev-zram2.device
          1.432s dev-zram3.device
```

Comment: At a terminal window, type _man rabbitmq-server.service_

Answer (score 1):

For a long time, systems like websites were built as so called monoliths. There was *one*, sometimes very large, piece of software. Today, many systems are a combination of multiple, sometimes of many smaller independent services (the keyword here is *microservices*). In a shop website for example, there could be one service handling the front-end interface, another service handling the communication with payment services like credit card companies, yet another service handling the stock-keeping of products and so forth.

To work together properly, those individual services need to "talk" to each other. One way for them to do that is using a *message broker*. That's a service of its own that basically relies messages back and forth between the individual services. That may be in some kind of queue, that may be in a publisher / subscriber model or with some other kind of architecture.

[RabbitMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ) is such a message broker. Why it is installed on your server and who is sending messages to whome with it, is something we can only guess.